# Callback function issue jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, callback

I have an issue with an if in a callback function and I don't understand why.

After clicking on a div, the text is changing as I would like, but after the first shot it doesn't work anymore.

My code is :

```
<div id="2">message</div>
<div id="1">dfdfgdfgrr</div>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {

$('#2').toggle();

function test() {
    $(document).on('click', '#1', function () {
        $('#2').toggle(300, function() {
            if($('#1').text('show')){
                $('#1').text('hide');
            }else{
                $('#1').text('show');
            }
        });
   });
}

test();


});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/manguo_manguo/cydjY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#1').text(function(i, t) { return t == 'show' ? 'hide' : 'show' });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      if($('#1').text() === 'show'){
            $('#1').text('hide');
        }else{
            $('#1').text('show');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$('#1').text("show")` instead of `$('#1').text() == "show"`

```
$('#2').toggle();

function test() {
    $(document).on('click', '#1', function () {
        $('#2').toggle(300, function() {
            if($('#1').text() == 'show'){
                $('#1').text('hide');
            }else{
                $('#1').text('show');
            }
        });
   });
}

test();
```

Answer (score 1):

The other solution are correct, but the first time it is not shown the **show** label.

This is a complete solution:

```
$(function () {

$('#2').toggle();

function test() {
    $(document).on('click', '#1', function () {
        $('#2').toggle(300, function() {
            if($('#1').text() == 'hide'){
                $('#1').text('show');
            }else{
                $('#1').text('hide');
            }
        });
   });
}

test();
$('#1').text('show');
});
```

Try an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/markus85/qq9HG/)